# how to create continues executing script in php with no execution limit

Tags: php

i have created a script to continuously listen from `SMSC` to catch the delivered SMS. script looks OK but want to make sure it never stops.

1. In [One post](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php#33462) it is stated that server may interfere the
   continuous execution and could stop the execution, but could not
   find any option in `httpd.conf` to disable the execution limit.
2. Secondly is below script is going to take `100% CPU` usage? as some
   other application are running on the same server.
3. Third what medium is better? `Browser` or  `php CLI`?

would appreciate any help or any reading material on stated problem. using `window server, XAMPP with apache 2.2, php 5.2.9`

```
set_time_limit(0);

do{
//read incoming sms
$sms=$tx->readSMS();
//check sms data
if($sms && !empty($sms['source_addr']) && !empty($sms['destination_addr']) && !empty($sms['short_message'])){
    //send sms for processing in smsadv
    $from=$sms['source_addr'];
    $to=$sms['destination_addr'];
    $message=$sms['short_message'];
     // insert in database...
}
//continuously check for SMS
}while(1);
```

**EDIT**
As per below response i used PHP script with `CLI` and without `set_time_limit(0)` as in script running through CLI has no execution limit.

Comment: This wouldn't be a good idea, Instead you could schedule `.php` script to run on specific time interval.

Comment: yes, it'll take 100% cpu while php is running, and 0% while it's waiting for a tcp response from your "readSMS()" (probably).

Comment: Change the script so it will process the received SMS and exit. Use the scheduled tasks manager to execute it every minute using CLI.

Comment: @Log1c is still not good if i use CLI

Comment: Yup, Better way would be `cron` (if on linux)

Comment: @gontrollez our SMSC is configured to check the receiver and after two  attempts discard the sms. i doubt i might miss some responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CLI script because the typical scenario of using PHP on server side to provide dynamic web pages isn't designed to have script running "forever". As advised in comments you might use scheduler script to be requested by browser frequently. If you don't plan to use brwoser at all, use CLI instead.

Regarding CPU load you might consider inserting `sleep(1)` in your while loop (in case of you're polling for incoming SMS rather than waiting for it as presumed in comments on question.

Comment: thanks. scheduler is not best suited as minimum iteration is 5 Min. so i used PHP through cli and it working perfectly